# old LLC - revival question and Tax implication

Tags: united-states, taxes, limited-liability-company

I have a LLC in AZ that I opened in 2007 for consulting purpose on the side, filed taxes on it the first year then life got busy and did not do any consulting on the side for last 7 yrs and never filed any taxes on that LLC since the first year. Now, I'm thinking about going back into consulting.

What are the thoughts on filing back on the LLC, issues in the gap for last 6 years, etc. according to the online corporation state site, it is in good standing. Any advice, including dissolving and reopening, etc, and whatever I need to do to get it restarted?

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, AZ doesn't require any filings from LLCs once they're created and in good standing. I have an AZ foreign LLC (registered in CA) and I make no special filings with AZ for it other than the initial registration.